# implode with characters after 6 word in php

Tags: php, string, implode

**I have a variable**

```
$srch_key = '180265180235' ;
```

**I want to make this output as**

```
'180265','180235'
```

That means I want to append those characters after 6 words or numbers.

I have tried this code to make it.

**Here is the code**

```
function ref_format($str, $step, $reverse = false)
{
    if ($reverse)
        return strrev("'" .  implode("' ,'", str_split($str, $step)) . "'");
    return "'" . implode("','", str_split($str, $step)) . "'";
}
  $passport = ref_format("$srch_key", 6);
  echo $passport_key = substr($passport, 0, -1);
```

**But The Output was**

```
'180265','180235
```

**But I want this output**

```
'180265','180235'
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made It

```
$srch_key = '180265180235' ;

  function ref_format($str, $step, $reverse = false)
{
    if ($reverse)
        return strrev("'" .  implode("' ,'", str_split($str, $step)) . "'");
    return "'". implode("', '", str_split($str, $step)) . "'";
}
  $passport = ref_format("$srch_key", 6);
  echo $passport_key = substr($passport, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$srch_key = '180265180235' ;

$k1 = substr($srch_key, 0,6);
$k2 = substr($srch_key, 6);

print("'{$k1}','{$k2}'");
```

Comment: You should add an explanation so OP understands the solution not just remembers it :&

Comment: edit answer with reference link :) makes it more complete :)